# RTSP Streaming Servers to broadcast receiving RTP packets from other system

Tags: nokia, smartphone, rtp, rtsp, live-streaming

I am developing a live video streaming application on Nokia N97. I have video and audio buffer in H.263 and AMR format respectively (from live camera source) and want to stream these to some sever that can broadcast it with RTSP. That RTSP broadcast server will be on internet. I need to know which RTSP servers can do this job that can receive audio and video streams in some format (like RTP) as input and broadcast it with RTSP.

Thanks for any idea and suggestions.

Jawad

Answer (score 0):

Darwin can easily do it. 
http://dss.macosforge.org/